# Is there a way to shorthand useSelector instead of causing unnecessary renders?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Consider both these calls

```
const loading = useSelector((state) => state.example.loading); 
const { loading } = useSelector((state) => state.example);
```

`const { loading } = useSelector((state) => state.example);` would make the component cause an unnecessary render whenever the other variable in the example slice changes. This one `const loading = useSelector((state) => state.example.loading);` wont because it only gets the `loading` variable.

In an app that I'm cleaning up a group member wrote `const { var1, var2, var3....var50 } = useSelector((state) => state.example);` and its causing unnecessary renders throughout the app. Instead of rewriting

```
const var1 = useSelector((state) => state.example.var1);
const var2 = useSelector((state) => state.example.var2);
...
```

Is there anyway to shorthand this but without causing a render?

playground example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-dew-7pfclw?file=/src/Header.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. You could create an object with all the values you actually want and then use a shallow compare with your reducer to make sure it doesn't rerender too often.

It might be less code, but honestly I'm not sure if it would be more readable.

You could also look into other selector libraries using proxies to track when to update. [there are some alternative candiates mentioned in the redux docs](https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors#proxy-memoize), you might be interested in `proxy-memoize`.

Answer (score 0):

Define the variable you want to get: `let var1, var2, var3, var4, ...;`

Assign value to those variable inside `useSelector` function:

```
let var1, var2, var3, var4, var5...;
const obj = useSelector(({example}) => {var1 = example.var1; var2 = example.var2; var3 = example.var3; var4 = example.var4; var5 = example.var5
  return {var1, var2, var3, var4, var5}
 });
```

Example of your playground example: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-bhabha-9b9qoq?file=/src/Header.js

Comment: Don't do this, it will never cause a rerender since the selector always returns `undefined`. For rerenders to be correct, the return value of `useSelector` has to be correct.

Comment: Thank you @phry, if `useSelector` return a obj with wanted value as what I have update in my post, can it rerender correct?

Comment: It would probably rerender too often, since it would rerender on every change of any property of that object, while OP only wants it to rerender if the specific properties change that they are interested in.

Comment: @phry Thank you for your insight and guidance.